# How to change underline border in paper input Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I want to change an underline border in paper input in Polymer but I don't know how to do it. Any idea?

If I inspect the component, what I want to change is the back color, but is indexed inside a classes of the component. Should I make a queryselector? How I call that class?

Thanks.

Comment: please provide some markup for this.

Comment: some code would help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mentioned in the docs that `paper-input` can be styled similar to [`paper-input-decorator`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-input-decorator).

To change the underline you'll want to use the new CSS `/deep/` combinator.

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
  paper-input /deep/ .unfocused-underline {
    /* line color when the input is unfocused */
    background-color: green;
  }
  paper-input /deep/ .focused-underline {
    /* line color when the input is focused */
    background-color: orange;
  }
</style>
```

Here's an example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cagaq/2/edit).

Because I'm using a style tag outside of a Polymer element, I've also included a `shim-shadowdom` attribute. If your styles are defined inside a Polymer element you won't need this.

Comment: /deep/ is bring deprecated. Now what? :(

Comment: You can use custom properties on input-container now https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container